# Em que parte da semântica do HTML5 coloco um form?

Tags: html5

No topo do site tenho um `<form>` de busca. Na semântica do HTML5 dentro de qual tag coloco este `<form>`. Tipo: section, article, etc...

```
<form name="buscaguia">
<input type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="Buscar no Guia Comercial">
<button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há um lugar exato onde você deveria colocar o form existe a contextualização do seu form afinal não é contextual você colocar um form em uma lista de exibição de itens como uma lista de blogs.
 tendo em vista isso agora faz sentido você colocar o form em um local destinado a adição e edição de seu blog.

Comment: Muito obrigado!